# Outlook Email - REGEX to allow Reply/Forward Emails in Subject

Tags: java, regex, outlook

I need REGEX to allow Reply and Forward emails in Automation. if reply/forward email comes with Ticket No INCxxxxx|SRxxxx (eg. INC123456 , SR45678), need to allow this , otherwise (reply/forward email without ticket no) should be ignore this.

List of Steps followed:

- Convert Email Subject to UpperCase
- Using REGEX `RE:.*|FW:.*` to allow Reply/Forward Email
- Using further REGEX `.*INC[0-9]+.*|.*SR[0-9]+.*` to finout TicketNo came or not in Email Subject.

I know multiple kind of combinations(RE:|RE :|FW:|FW :|FWD:|FWD : etc) will come when we consider reply/forward emails.

Ticket No Fetching:

```
String input = "issue with outlook INC7681499";
     String pattern = "(?i)(INC|SR)\\d+";
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

     while (m.find()) {
         String ticketNo=m.group(1);
        System.out.println("Found value: " + ticketNo );
        
}
```

Is there any other best way to achieve this?

Comment: it can convert to `(RE|FWD?) ?:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert email subjects to uppercase if you make your regex case-insensitive by using the `(?i)` flag.

Your use of `|` is quite broad in your regex, you are essentially specifying a full subject match with every option. You can restrict it to only "OR" between the parts that change.

```
(?i)(RE|FWD?)\s*:
(?i)(INC|SR)\d+
```

If you make use of the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, you can also do away with `.*` at either end with `Matcher.find()` which supports sub-string matches.

A sub-string match will also allow any common tags in subjects, like, *FYI/Urgent/Important RE/FWD:*, and with `Matcher.group()` you can extract the ticked IDs very easily if there's a need for it later on.

---

You can capture the ticket no. with `(?i)(INC|SR)\d+` too as the complete sub-string match is always available by calling `Matcher.group()` *without passing any index* or by calling `Matcher.group(0)`.

```
String input = "issue with outlook INC7681499";
String regex = "(?i)(INC|SR)\\d+";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Ticket no. " + matcher.group()); // INC7681499
}
```

From [Groups and capturing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Capturing groups are numbered by counting their opening parentheses
> from left to right. In the expression `((A)(B(C)))`, for example, there
> are **four** such groups:
>
> ```
> 1. ((A)(B(C)))
> 2. (A)
> 3. (B(C))
> 4. (C)
> ```
>
> **Group zero always stands for the entire expression.**

So, with nested brackets `(?i)((INC|SR)\d+)` you'll end up creating a redundant capture group:

```
0. (INC|SR)\d+
1. (INC|SR)\d+
2. (INC|SR)
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi K Thapliyal,
Thanks for your suggestion, while fetching ticket no, i got only "INC" or "SR" , but i want whole ticket no (INC123456 or SR45678). Please check code added in above question.

Comment: Hi @Ravi K Thapliyal,
I try to use REGEX like "(?i)((INC|SR)\\d+)" to extract exact Ticket no from Email Subject. the above REGEX works fine. any other best way always welcome and Thank you

Comment: Hi @Justin, you can capture the ticket no. with the old regex too. I've added an example and explained capture groups in detail.